# Hybris Commerce - How to expose Web Services

Tags: web, service, sap-commerce-cloud, commerce

I'm fairly new to Hybris Commerce and its extensions. I installed Hybris 5.7 and 6 and (hopefully) installed the platformwebservices extensions this way:

- I added these entries to localextensions.xml:

> ```
> <extension name='tomcatembeddedserver' />
> <extension name='platformservices' />
> <extension name='lucenesearch' />
> <extension name='platformwebservices' />
> ```

- Ran ant clean all
- Started the Hybris Server

In the admin UI under Platform/Extensions I see this:

[image]

What do those two red X mean for the platformwebservices extension. Are the rest services now exposed?

EDIT: It seems the services are running. But I get a 403 Forbidden response. This is what I enter with cUrl:

```
curl -u admin:nimda http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries
```

Answer (score 1):

They mean :

- No "coremodule" for this extension ("A core module consists of an items.xml file, a manager class, classes for the JaLo Layer and the ServiceLayer and JUnit 
  test classes. The following directories are required: /src, /resources, /testsrc")
- No "hmcmodule" for this extension ("Configures an hMC module for the extension. Required directory: /hmc.Used to configure the HMC")

So yes they are exposed from an extension that doesn't have a core and hmc module that's all.

Comment: It seems the services are running. But I get a 403 Forbidden response. This is what I enter with cUrl:

curl -u admin:nimda http://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/countries

Comment: Doesn't work with the admin user you need to create a new user member of the occ group if I remember correctly

Comment: Found the solution: It seems that the admin user was not part of the webservicegroup. After performing a system update with "Create essential data" checkbox checked, that usergroup was created and it finally worked.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution: It seems that the admin user was not part of the webservicegroup. After performing a system update with "Create essential data" checkbox checked, that usergroup was created and it finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

It just says whether that particular extension contains that hyrbis module or not.

You could see it to the right on small panel on the same screen as mentioned in your question.

[image: Hybris Info]

I am not sure exactly how `platformwebservices` extension work as I never used it.

Regarding webservices, you need to add `webmodule` to your extension and then you can use spring based controllers to expose webservices. Might need to add following line to your extensions info to add `webmodule`.

```
<webmodule jspcompile="false" webroot="/rest" />
```